# how to optimization with pyomo?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I have a dataframe:

```
d = {'Doctors': [20, 19,25], 'Nurses': [151, 131,160],'Outpatients':[100,150,160],'Inpatients':[90,50,55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

and a vector like: W=[v1,v2,u1,u2] I want to solve following problem:

Max  (100u1+90u2)

s.t

(20v1+151v2)=1

&

(100u1+90u2)-(20v1+151v2)<=0

(150u1+50u2)-(19v1+131v2)<=0

(160u1+55u2)-(25v1+160v2)<=0

&

v1,v2,u1,u2>=0

How can I solve this problem in pyomo?
can anyone give me  some  advise please?

Comment: What have you tried?  Your problem isn't too complicated.  Advice:  Stay away from combining pandas and pyomo until you are comfortable w/ pyomo.  Just put the data in a dictionary, use a `ConcreteModel` and 4 variables for your `W` vector...  The dox have several examples on setting up small models.

Comment: Thanks @AirSquid but it's a small dataset. Original problem have a n*n matrix (n=30)

Comment: the size of the original problem is not really relevant.  If you can set up the structure of the model correctly, it scales easily.  It isn't clear how your data frame snippet relates to the equations, but the format of the equations is quite standard for a linear program and should be fairly straightforward to incorporate into a pyomo framework or something similar.